# Custom UITableViewCell doesn't respond on textLabel touches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have custom `UITableViewCell`. It contains `UITextLabel`.
When I press this cell over the label it doesn't respond, but if I touch it on empty area, then is responds. What might be the problem?

My Cell is made in IB, User Interaction is enabled. Also, I've noticed that this problem happens only on iPad, on iPhone everything works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was another view on top of `UITableView`

Answer (score 2):

Go to IB of your CustomCell and make userinteraction disabled for the label.

Answer (score 0):

check the frame of your textLabel. If the frame of your textLabel is exceeding your UITableViewCell, it will not respond to touch events.